Alexa-SDK: The following directives are not supported: Dialog.ElicitSlot
I'm trying to make a skill that requires the user to login in order to pull their data from a separate database. For this, I need the user's email. Initially, I had it so the skill's LaunchRequestHandler would welcome the user and then immediately use elicit_slot_directive to forward them into a separate CaptureEmailIntent. Instead, I keep getting the following error:
"error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "The following directives are not supported: Dialog.ElicitSlot"
        }

When browsing stack overflow for someone with a similar problem, all I could find was this. It seems their issue was specifically in the case of in skill purchase, so it's not quite the same. My code is as follows:
class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler que lida com o lançamento da skill caso o usuário nunca tenha logado."""

    def can_handle(self, handler_input: HandlerInput) -> bool:
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input: HandlerInput) -> Response:
        speak_output = (
            "Olá! Bem vindo ao Conecta Car. Antes de começar, precisarei que me diga o email vinculado à sua conta."
            + " Caso não possua uma conta, por favor, crie uma no aplicativo Conecta Car e tente novamente."
        )
        reprompt_text = "Por favor, me diga o email vinculado à sua conta."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder.add_directive(
                elicit_slot_directive.ElicitSlotDirective(
                    updated_intent=Intent(name="CaptureEmailIntent"),
                    slot_to_elicit="email",
                )
            )
            .speak(speak_output)
            .ask(reprompt_text)
            .response
        )

